# Bash tab completion not working following = character

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, autocomplete

I've looked at a lot of bash tab completion questions and haven't yet found one that answers this one.

I'm on a linux system (GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)) and normally tab completion works just fine.

However, when I go to use tab completion for an environment variable or command-line option, it fails. For example,

`ls /v<TAB>` -> `ls /var/`
`export FOO=/v<TAB>` -> `export FOO=/v` (bell plays)

When I do this on my Mac (GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)) tab completion of the environment variable value works fine.

On both machines, `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` is `"'><=;|&(:`.

Someone (I don't know where this came from) suggested that

`shopt -u progcomp`

might help, and it does fix the problem! However, I don't need to unset that option Mac-side and I'm worried it might cause other strange side effects.

Is that a normal thing to unset? Is there anything else I can do to figure this out?

Comment: `Blabla=` requires anything whatsoever to follow. What should the completion suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shopt -u progcomp` disables [programmable completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html), i.e. scripts that may provide e.g. per-program completion. They might provide features like only completing files that match `*.tar` or such when the command line starts with `tar`, etc. Those scripts usually come with your distribution, or not, in the case of the Mac.

It's fine to disable `progcomp` if the bugs and misfeatures caused by those scripts seem more annoying than the actual features are useful (and for me, that's about 100 % of the time).

Comment: Thank you — that both reassures me that things are okay _and_ gives me somewhere to look for something broken. If turning off progcomp makes this work correctly, then it's a pretty good bet that something is borked with those rules.